# Help with the inequality $P(X=0)\leq \frac{Var(X)}{E(X^2)}$ where $E[X]>0$, $X\in L^2$

Tags: probability, inequality

I hope you can help me to understand the solution for the following inequality where $E[X]>0$, $X\in L^2$:

$$P(X=0)\leq \frac{Var(X)}{E(X^2)}$$

This is the first step but I don't understand it

$$P(X=0) \stackrel{\text{Mon.}}\le P(|X-E(X)|\ge E(X))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that for any two positive random variables $X, Y$ we have
$$E[XY]^2 \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2]$$
which follows from Cauchy-Schwartz by defining the inner product on two random variables $\langle X, Y \rangle = E[X Y]$. You can verify that it satisfies all the properties of an inner product, and so it also must satisfy the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. By choosing $X = X$ (from your problem) and $Y = I_{X \neq 0}$ to be the indicator of the event where $X \neq 0$, the above inequality implies
$$E[XY]^2 = E[X]^2 \leq E[X^2] E[Y^2] = E[X^2] E[Y] = E[X^2] \cdot P(X \neq 0)$$
The first equality follows because the case where $X = 0$ doesn't contribute to the expectation, so clearly $E[X \cdot I_{X \neq 0}] = E[X]$. The second equality follows because $Y$ is an indicator random variable, and hence $Y^2 \sim Y$. Rearranging, we get
$$P(X \neq 0) \geq \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]} \implies P(X = 0) \leq 1 - \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]} = \frac{E[X^2] - E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}$$
which yields your desired inequality as the numerator is just the definition of variance. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

The event $(X=0)$ is contained in the event $(|X-EX| \geq EX)$. Hence $P(X=0) \leq P(|X-EX| \geq EX)$.

Comment: Doesn't this only imply that $P(X = 0) \leq \sigma^2 / (EX)^2$? But $EX^2 \geq (EX)^2$ so this doesn't prove the desired implication...